# how to attach key press event on table cell in react js

Tags: reactjs

i have a table i wanna attach arrow keys to each cell  wanna implement something like https://jsfiddle.net/rh5aoxsL/ in react but then not able to do so as some where m going wrong can anyone lemme know what has to be done

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import './App.css';
 class App extends Component {
   constructor(props){
super(props);
this.escFunction = this.escFunction.bind(this);
   }
   escFunction(event){
   if(event.keyCode === 37) {
    console.log("----------37---------------");
    }
    if(event.keyCode === 38) {
   console.log("----------38---------------");
    }
    if(event.keyCode === 39) {
    console.log("----------39---------------");
    }
    if(event.keyCode === 40) {
    console.log("----------40---------------");
    }
    }
 componentDidMount(){
document.addEventListener("keydown", this.escFunction, false);
 }
  componentWillUnmount(){
   document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.escFunction, false);
 }
 render() {
   return (  
    <div className="App">      
    <table >
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td id="start" onKeyDown={this.escFunction}>1</td>
        <td onKeyDown={this.escFunction}>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td onKeyDown={this.escFunction}>3</td>
        <td onKeyDown={this.escFunction}>4</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    );
   }
  }

 export default App;
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: You need to attach key listen event on the document like the jquery example you gave. This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069639/listen-to-keypress-for-document-in-reactjs

Comment: @pradeep i have added it keydown  as event listner but then how do i attach it to  table cell. <td>

Comment: You don't have any `handleKeyPress` but you are using in the callback. So shouldn't it be `escFunction`?

Comment: ya i had pasted wrong code onkeydown i have to use escFunction@devserkan

Comment: have you got solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is my code, just getting siblings.

Constants:

```
const UP_ARROW = 38;
const DOWN_ARROW = 40;
const LEFT_ARROW = 37;
const RIGHT_ARROW=39;
const TOTAL_CELLS_BY_ROW = (your_number_of_cols);
```

I have tr -> td -> div -> input, my focus is in inputs. (this is why i have some parentElement and childNodes.

TOTAL_CELLS_BY_ROW is my col count...

```
   onKeyDown = (e) => {
        var idx = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.cellIndex;

        if (e.keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
            if (e.target.parentElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling) {
                e.target.parentElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].focus();
            }
        }

        if (e.keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
            if (e.target.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling) {
                e.target.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].focus();
            }
        }

        if (e.keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
            const nextRow = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling
            if (nextRow) {
                nextRow.childNodes[idx%TOTAL_CELLS_BY_ROW].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].focus();
            }
        }

        if (e.keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
            const previousRow = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling
            if (previousRow) {
                previousRow.childNodes[idx%TOTAL_CELLS_BY_ROW].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].focus();
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course `onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}` in each input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this code is enough for you but as @Pardeep Dhingra explained in the comments you need `onKeyDown` instead of `onKeyPress` in your situation. Also, you should change your callback function. I've used `tabIndex` to start the initial move.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  escFunction = ( event ) => {
    if ( event.keyCode === 37 ) {
      console.log( "----------37---------------" );
    }
    if ( event.keyCode === 38 ) {
      console.log( "----------38---------------" );
    }
    if ( event.keyCode === 39 ) {
      console.log( "----------39---------------" );
    }
    if ( event.keyCode === 40 ) {
      console.log( "----------40---------------" );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td id="start" tabIndex="0" onKeyDown={this.escFunction}>
                1
              </td>
              <td onKeyDown={this.escFunction}>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td onKeyDown={this.escFunction}>3</td>
              <td onKeyDown={this.escFunction}>4</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: how do  i  move to the td and select using arrow keys?

Comment: If you click the body and hit TAB you will be in `1`. Then arrow keys work. But, I'm not so experienced with event listeners. This is all that I can provide :)

Comment: me too not that experienced  only this part me too i have achieved.