# react can't access state from document/window keypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given the example below

```css
#app div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

div:focus {
  background: red;
}

div:focus:before {
  content: "focused";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
  let { useState, useRef, Fragment } = React; 
  let App = () => { 
    let [, forceUpdate] = useState(); 
    let [num, setNum] = useState(0); 
    let history = useRef('null'); 
    
    let keyPressHandler = () => { 
    history.current = num; 
    
    // just to force an update 
    forceUpdate(Date.now());
  }; 
  
  return (
  <Fragment>
    <button onClick={()=>{setNum(Date.now())}}>update state</button>
    <div tabindex="0" onKeyPress={keyPressHandler}>this div has a keypress listener. <br/>for now whatever key you press it will save the state in a ref, that changes on the button click. <br/>Click the button to change the state then focus this div then press any key to save the state in the ref</div>
    <div>State&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: {num}</div>
    <div>History: {history.current}</div>
  </Fragment>
  ); 
}; 

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
</script>
```

Now i'm going to move the key press listener to the window, should do the same thing.

```css
#app div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
  let { useEffect, useState, useRef, Fragment } = React; 
  let App = () => { 
    let [, forceUpdate] = useState(); 
    let [num, setNum] = useState(0); 
    let history = useRef('null'); 
    
    useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keypress", keyPressHandler);
   }, []);
    
    let keyPressHandler = () => { 
    console.log('called keyPressHandler')
    history.current = num; 
    
    // just to force an update 
    forceUpdate(Date.now());
  }; 
  
  return (
  <Fragment>
    <button onClick={()=>{setNum(Date.now())}}>update state</button>
    <div>State&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: {num}</div>
    <div>History: {history.current}</div>
  </Fragment>
  ); 
}; 

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
</script>
```

But it doesn't `num`(state) is always the initial value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listen to keypress for document in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069639/listen-to-keypress-for-document-in-reactjs)

Comment: Just tried `keyDown` same problem, i don't think it's a problem with which event

Comment: what are you trying to prove here man if you are not using sate simply use `history.current = history.current + '-' + key`

Comment: @saurabh i have two states and `history.current` is null by default when one of the states changes i store the other one in `history.current`

Comment: that's exactly my question is why do you want to do that if you are using `useref` then you can simply use ` history.current =  history.current + '-' + key` and for the state you can directly use val in the jsx

Comment: all of these doesn't align with the question you initially asked, please ask a new question. A separate from this one stating what exactly you want to ask.

Comment: I don't want to append to the history, i want to access the new state and assign it to the history

Comment: you can do that using `useEffect()` and also refer this for more understanding [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867616/console-log-the-state-after-using-usestate-doesnt-return-the-current-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867616/console-log-the-state-after-using-usestate-doesnt-return-the-current-value)

Comment: @saurabh updated the question should be much more clear what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that when the window rerender only accesses the `val` variable in the first render, it doesn't have access to the new `val` in the subsequent render.

state hooks also have a callback, in which the current state is passed in.

In this case, using a callback to read the latest state value and to ensure that you have the latest state value before add it will solve the problem.

example:

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/babel">
let { useEffect, useState } = React;
let App = () => {

 let [val, setVal] = useState('initial Value')
  
  useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("keypress", keyPressHandler);
  // document.addEventListener("keypress", keyPressHandler);
 }, []);
  
  let keyPressHandler = ({ key }) => {
    console.log(val)
  setVal(val => val + "-" + key); /*<- change this line*/
 };
  
 return (
  <div tabindex="0" >
   <h1>{val}</h1>
  </div>
 );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));

</script>
```

**UPDATED**

As for the question asked by Zohir Salak in the comment.
I will recommend reading this blog by Dan Abramov. [link](https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/)

**EDIT**

As the question got updated

the best way to do that will be using the a state to store the history value

if you want to use `useref` then the way I can think of is

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
  let { useEffect, useState, useRef, Fragment } = React; 
  let App = () => { 
    let [,ForceUpdate] = useState(); 
    let [keyUpdate, setKeyUpdate] = useState(0); 
    let [num, setNum] = useState(0); 
    let history = useRef('null'); 
    
    useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keypress", keyPressHandler);
   }, []);
    
    let keyPressHandler = () => { 
    console.log('called keyPressHandler');
    setKeyUpdate(Date.now());
  }; 
    
  useEffect(() => {history.current = num; ForceUpdate(Date.now())  }, [keyUpdate]);
    
  
    
  return (
  <Fragment>
    <button onClick={()=>{setNum(Date.now())}}>update state</button>
    <div>State&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: {num}</div>
    <div >History: {history.current}</div>
  </Fragment>
  ); 
}; 

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
</script>
```

Comment: This may solve the problem but i'm looking for a much thorough answer that explains why this is happening, because as you know in a class component i don't have to do any of this.

Comment: well the question is `react can't access state from document/window keypress
`  and also both of the demo used doesn't use classes

Comment: Your solution only works if i want to update the state, but in some cases i just want to access the new state and do something with it without updating the state

Comment: I didn't get that, can you give an example?

Comment: Having a second state defies the purpose, now there will be a rerender on every key stroke

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to register listener in each update. Alternative you can store the state in a service or in a variable or using useRef hook.

**Demo**

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/babel">
let { useEffect, useState } = React;
let App = () => {

 let [val, setVal] = useState('initial Value')
  
  useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("keypress", keyPressHandler);
  // document.addEventListener("keypress", keyPressHandler);
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener("keypress", keyPressHandler);
        }
 });
  
  let keyPressHandler = ({ key }) => {
    console.log(val)
  setVal(val + "-" + key);
 };
  
 return (
  <div tabindex="0" >
   <h1>{val}</h1>
  </div>
 );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));

</script>
```

Comment: that sounds heavy don't you think ? i mean i can't just use a class component and i wouldn't have to register the listener on every update

Comment: It depends. You can also save your status outside the component in a service or in a variable. For example let AppState = {}.

Comment: that defies the purpose of using state

Comment: Performance should not be your first problem. If you have performance issues you can use services, or variables as transient state.